# Input part of a CSS file into another without ruining the design

Tags: css, mobile-website

I have a website already made. I want to make a mobile version of this. I basically want to import a table from the main site into the mobile site. I want to take the CSS code from the main site that covers the table and then input in my CSS file for the mobile site (I already put the HTML code into the mobile site). The problem is, when I do that it starts to overwrite the current CSS file and change the design.

Help please!!

Comment: We need a little more specific information. Are you using media queries? this question has a good answer for that that might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364109/best-way-to-use-media-queries-for-mobile-designs

Comment: No, I'm not using media queries. I had never heard of them until just now. I just want to get a table containing links from my main site to my mobile site.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use media queries. This is a css3 function.
In the top of your html, you need to put the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Then, in your css, you will do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

This is a reference site for commonly used media queries.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

You will basically need to do this for each size device you are optimizing for.
Also, if you have several of these, you might end up with a very large css file.
That could impede download speed especially on a phone. In that case, create
separate smaller css files and use conditional statements in your html to specify
which css to call. In that case, you will need to use something like this in your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/assets/css/small-device.css" />
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But I don't see how that would allow me to input the table from my main site into my mobile site.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please provide some code or something that is more descriptive than your OP?

Comment: best practice when designing a responsive website is not to have separate html files, but to use one html file that you adjust using only the css. Ideally, you would start with your mobile site - being as that is typically the most basic version - and you would improve the site using css only as the device size gets progressively larger. If you were doing it that way, you wouldn't need to import a table. You'd only need to reformat it.

Comment: Some other thoughts - if you are using php, you could create an include. If you are using html, you could use an iframe - although those aren't that common anymore. I'm not sure why people have gotten away from using them though.

Comment: Oh ok. See, what I did was I created to separate sites... Both of them were from templates. I did that because one looked better on mobile devices than the other, so I kinda needed separate sites. And what code could I show you?

Comment: Next time you do it, plan carefully and you can make your mobile site and your large screen site look totally different without having separate sites. When you have time, do some research on responsive web design.

Comment: Do you have a link to the large screen site?

Comment: An example of one of the tables I need is: http://myshows.us/Anger-Management.html

Comment: Alright, this might not be the best way to go, but it's an idea: Make that section into an iframe. Then import the iframe into both the large screen site and the mobile site. Create a media query for the two different sizes (although you should really have more than two to accomodate various devices) and call it from within the iframe's html.

Comment: Well I already tried an iFrame. That didn't work because it put the whole page in there. I couldn't find a way to isolate the table. I would be totally fine iFraming just the table if I new how.

Comment: you have to create an html page with JUST the table in it. Then you have to import it into both the large screen display page and the mobile display page using an iframe.