# detecting mobile device and then adding separate stylesheet

Tags: php, mobile, stylesheet

I'm having some problems with added separate stylesheets when detecting mobile and tablet devices. I currently have the following at the top of my header file to detect mobile devices.

```
<?php if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobi') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) { $browser = 'mobile'; } ?>
```

However when I call the following within my head tags the stylesheet doesn't get called for some reason.

```
<?php if($browser == 'mobile'){ ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/stylesheets/mobile.css" /><?php } ?>
```

I've tested the first php code I wrote on this post by adding in `echo 'This is a mobile browser';` and this displays fine so the first bit is working. Just no idea why the stylesheet is not being called.

Here's an example of some css styles in mobile.css

```
div{
clear:both !important;
display:block !important;
width:100% !important;
float:none !important;
margin:0 !important;
padding:0 !important;
position: static !important;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: don't you have to echo the bloginfo? `<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`

Comment: Have you considered using selectors in css, e.g. so that some css rules only apply to small screens, others to large screens?

Comment: @TimJoyce echo is not required with bloginfo it just print result

Comment: @Tinku Rana yes, I've double checked this and even replaced the 'bloginfo' with the full url but still no luck

Comment: @mvds Yes, I have used for exampple `@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { /*some styles*/ }` to target portrait and landscape and have other specific ones to target just landscape / portrait. I could just add these to my main style.css file but ideal wanted separate stylesheets.

Comment: try  testing your site in online mobile simulator, then using firebug you may get some info about css

Comment: @keyaspects: Considering reliability and maintainability, I would always prefer using css standards above serverside user-agent detection. Every new mobile phone/browser could break a solution based on separate stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the problem of selecting CSS's using CSS media queries. Do they have a lack?

- http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries
- [Best way to use Media Queries for Mobile Designs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364109/best-way-to-use-media-queries-for-mobile-designs)
- http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: Nothing is changing at all. This is what I have in my stylesheet currently. `/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */

body{
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding:5px !important;
}

div{
  clear:both !important;
  display:block !important;
  width:100% !important;
  float:none !important;
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
  position: static !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use something more versatile like this: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/
2. Use Firebug or similar tool to see if stylesheet path is correct and recognized by browser.