# Mobile Wordpress Site without using a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

How do I make a mobile wordpress site without using a plugin? I am a developer but new to wordpress. I have a desktop version that I like a lot but it doesn't doesn't display correctly on a mobile site and the links are messed up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to use Media Queries for Mobile Designs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364109/best-way-to-use-media-queries-for-mobile-designs). Media queries work just fine for Wordpress. You can include as many stylesheets as you like and target your output HTML all without any Wordpress tricks.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, CSS Media queries will allow you to define CSS rules for certain devices based on screen resolution.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4+ ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

insert the rules in the /* Styles */ block to modify your site to suit the device.