# best way to use Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I've never used media queries before and I'm really not sure if my code will work properly on all devices. Therefor I want to ask you to speak from your experience and knowledge and tell me what problems may appear on some special/any devices.

After some reading, I decided to go with as simple as I thought way and used simple rule:

```
@media (max-width:504px){
/* My style for mobile/ipad etc */
}
@media (min-width:505px){
/* My style for laptops/desktop etc */
}
```

Comment: There are more than one correct ways to use media queries. Your approach seems valid but you could introduce more levels e.g. smartphone, tablet, desktop. Take a look to a CSS framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation. Check out their grid system, it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Check this post, it has some cases that might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364109/best-way-to-use-media-queries-for-mobile-designs

Comment: If you target only mobile/tablet devices (and new browsers of course), go ahead and use it as suggested by other answerers.

If not, some do have the method/property you want to use, some don't (even newer browsers).

One practice is to use "progressive enhancement", which simply means, make your web site work without the too fancy/cool stuff, so those with an ancient (or missing feature) browser still can view your site.

Then you "enhance" it with newer features, where media queries is an excellent feature to fit content in smaller displays like mobiles and tablets.

Comment: For example, if your site address both desktop and mobiles/tablets users, on desktop IE8 (as of today) still has many users, so here you better of with a page for desktop and then "enhance" it using media queries for mobile/tablet users.

Note: To really know which features you can/want to use, you need to figure out what your users use, and the best way is to create/study visitor statistics of your page, and based on that you can decide, which features will pay off start using and which not, or simple put, you calculate the loss of users and if "not to many", you add the feature(s).

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is still better to write CSS for one of two display sizes, and then override the styles with media query. Fo ex. mobile-first approach:

```
#some-element { font-size: 2em; }
.container { color: red; }
.another-class { width: 100px; }

@media (min-width: 505px) {
  #some-element { font-size: 1.5em; }
  .container { color: blue; }
}
```

This way have two advantages:

- You dont have to write the same code for two media queries, only overrides (you dont have to duplicate .another-class for media query).
- Ancient browsers without media queries support will render site using styles that are not in media query.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Of course you're right. I didn't mention it, but I assumed it.

Answer (score 0):

Artur answer is correct, old browsers like IE7 don't support media queries, but media queries design is intended mostly for moderns browsers, so creating a fallback CSS isn't exactly required unless you want to, mostly because some CSS properties (hiding certain elements with display:none for example) won't work so your intended web design will lose purpose. Each web designer have their own way of writing CSS, but I prefer this method:

```
body, html{

width:100%;
margin:0;
/* Base CSS that will affect all resolutions */ 
}

#elements-up-to-320px{
/* CSS for elements up to first media query */
}

@media (min-width:320px){
/* CSS for elements from 320px and up until next media query */
}

@media (min-width:480px){
/* CSS for elements from 480px and up until next media query */
}
```

This way it's more understandable and last CSS media query will apply for higher screen sizes.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@media is good if you want to create a CSS-Gridsystem (for example) It takes a parameter with the min-width or more. So you have the possibility to set different CSS-Propeties for different Screen-Sizes.

Links:

[SELFHTML](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries)

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Hope that helped you :)